# Collaborating on a single file

Tags: version-control, latex, collaboration, sharing

I'm working on a LaTeX project (a beamer presentation) with a friend and we would like to be able to work on it simultaneously. We tried using Dropbox for sharing the files, but we found out that it's very difficult to work on one file together. So my question is: is there a version control system that would allow to do this, so that the collaborators could apply their changes simultaneously (if the changes were disjoint)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, many versioning systems will allow simultaneous editing with merging of changes. I'm a fan of `git` for small projects like this.

You might also consider a real-time collaborative editor like `SubEthaEdit` or even Google Docs. Then you can both write in the same file at the same time, and see each others' changes as they are made--no merging necessary.

Comment: @ondra: I'd like to add that [ScribTeX](http://www.scribtex.com) is a online latex editor that lets you collaborate with others. I've used only the free version, which lets you collaborate with 1 other person per project. The paid version is more flexible and plans are also affordable. It also has a version control system that lets you roll back changes. In all, I've enjoyed using it.